# Which regular expressions (POSIX or extended) are allowed in awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I'm wondering which kind of regular expressions (POSIX as in grep, or extended in egrep)  am I using when type in regular expressions in awk?

Comment: @fedorqui I think the OP is asking if in AWK you have to use POSIX or extended regexes (as the one he uses with grep or respectively egrep)

Answer (score 0):

In AWK you can use extended regular expressions (as in `egrep`). From http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html

> The regular expressions in awk are a superset of the POSIX
>   specification for Extended Regular Expressions (EREs).